# What is the proper way to implement "type password again to continue" for critical actions in REST

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, api-design

As the title suggests, I'm trying to implement the mechanism of `retyping the password again` **before proceeding any critical action**, e.g. change email, deactivate an account, invites a new user, ... etc.

The problem is, I'm confused about how it should be done in the REST world.

Should it be like, first, use the password to authenticate the user, but with a different backing authentication made especially for this action and use the resulted token to access this protected resource later? E.g. a JWT token with a specific claim for this action and guard that endpoint with this custom authentication to authenticate for this custom token?

Or should it be done in one request providing the password and based on password check the action will be proceeded or denied?

Or should it be something else?

Thanks in advance for your help, I really appreciate it.

Note: I'm using DRF that's why I added it's the tag to the question, but as this is a general question

Comment: The simplest way by far is to just return a representation that politely asks the user to reenter his credentials via a form-based representation, such as HTML or hal+forms and keep the previously entered data in a temporary resource. Once the credentials got verified again, you can safely process the actual data according to your needs. This is how the Web work and this is also how REST should work ootb.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it right or not but here I go, the mentioned flow is the comomn one for web in general and will be for frontend too, I was thinking for the same flow for such a user, but if it was this way when it comes to REST, the second endpoint must be secured with somthing that won't allow accsess unless password was verified. that's the problem

Comment: In password change, for example, the old password along with the new password are supplied in one request, should I do the same for other things? or it's better to split as two steps? first enters password, get a diifrent token, accses the protected resource with it?